# Rename commit message after pushing to github

Tags: git, github

I have two commits that I just pushed to github

The 2nd commit message after the 1st commit message is actually a bit messed up.

Is there a way to change the 2nd commit message after pushing it to github?

I know amend will work only if it hasn't been pushed to github. No one hasn't branched off my current dev branch, so it's safe to assume that no one will be affected if I do this.

Comment: Amend doesn't know or care whether you've pushed. It will still work. You will just have to do a force push afterwards to tell the server that you're okay with a non-fast-forward update.

Comment: How do I ammend the 2nd commit from the last one though?

Comment: If other people have pulled the commit you're intending to modify, this is a very bad idea and will cause them lots of pain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using Git's interactive rebasing feature.  From git-rebase(1):

> -i, --interactive
>     Make a list of the commits which are about to be rebased. Let the
>     user edit that list before rebasing.

If you run `git rebase --interactive HEAD~2`, you'll be able to instruct Git to reword the second-most-recent commit message.  Chapter 6.4 in Scott Chacon's *Pro Git* has [a lot of good information about interactive rebasing](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History#Changing-Multiple-Commit-Messages).

As hobbs has already commented above, you'll still need to do a forced push.